# How to debug Groovy script in Visual Studio Code

Tags: groovy, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a groovy script which I want to debug in Visual Studio Code. I was thinking that groovy being a JVM language I may need to use the [Java Debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/09/28/java-debug). But I have not yet found a way to debug Groovy code. Any suggestion?

Comment: Should I move this to Superuser forum?

Comment: Just download the community version of IntelliJ and use the Java debugger from that IDE. It has good Groovy support. You shouldn't be using Visual Studio with Java.

Comment: [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) has got support for Java

Comment: That doesn't mean the support for Groovy is good enough

Comment: And it is indeed not good enough.  Syntax coloring fine, but missing characters, braces lost which leads to errors.